# How to know the size of the memory allocation of a shared object linked at runtime?

Tags: c, memory, shared-libraries, dlopen

After linking a share library (.so) with dlopen, how can we know the size of the linked shared object i.e till what offset from the handle returned by dlopen is the shared library allocated.

Comment: Why do you need to know this?

Comment: The shared object doesn't have to be a single block of memory. It can have different segments for text, data, BSS, just like an executable object file.

Comment: Can we know the offsets for data ? I want to make an offset table for the functions and data of the shared library.

Comment: Offset from what? The pointer returned by `dlopen` is opaque data, and may not have anything to do with the location of the shared object in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dynamic linking of the shared library is a complete userspace process. You could do it on your own: Parse the ELF headers of the file, mmap the file into memory, do the dynamic linking with undefined symbols of the shared library etc pp. Then you know exactly where the library parts are located. But GNU libdl doesn't provide any information with regard to that.

Another option is to dlopen() the library and parse /proc/self/maps for it. It usually has several mappings with different access permissions (code, rodata, rwdata, etc) depending on the elf header like that:

```
7fd6298f0000-7fd6298f5000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 393441 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.19.so
7fd6298f5000-7fd629af4000 ---p 00005000 fd:00 393441 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.19.so
7fd629af4000-7fd629af5000 r--p 00004000 fd:00 393441 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.19.so
7fd629af5000-7fd629af6000 rw-p 00005000 fd:00 393441 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.19.so
```

This should provide all information you need.